# Product of linear and decreasing function has only one maxima

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I want to prove this statement:
Suppose $g(x)$ is a decreasing function $\forall x>0$, hence $xg(x)$ has only one maxima $\forall x>0$.

Graphically it is clear that it has one maxima, but I need to prove it mathematically.

This question is similar to the one in [Product of linear and convex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272022/product-of-linear-and-convex-function). I went through the answer, but I think it is not correct (when he gets the second derivative).

Can someone help?

Comment: Maybe you mean "at most one local max" (as Stefano's example shows there may be no local maxes at all...)

Comment: $g(x)$ is constant $\forall x > 0$, and $g(x)=1/x$ is a counterexample for the correct phrasing of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is false as it is. Take $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2}$. Then $g$ is decreasing for $x >0$, but $x g(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$ is convex.

Comment: Thank you @Stefano. I wrote the question in wrong way. I want to prove that it has only one maxima.

Comment: The same example as above shows that $xg(x)$ has no maximum :/ @user137776

Comment: Maybe OP means "at most one local max".

Answer (score 0):

The argument is wrong, though it follows in many "non-artificial" scenarios. Here is a function which is a product of a linear and a strictly decreasing function. The product has two maxima. [Use this google plot for visualising](https://www.google.com/search?q=x(e%5E(-0.5x)%2Be%5E(-50x%5E5))&rlz=1C5GCEM_enSE946SE946&oq=x(e%5E(-0.5x)%2Be%5E(-50x%5E5))&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.411j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
$$f(x)=x(e^{-0.5x}+e^{-50x^5})$$

PS: Late answer but might be useful for someone else.